# Word for someone who makes you feel good about yourself

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that would describe someone who is really good at making others feel good about themselves. Someone who is always bringing others up and who is kind and genuine.

Comment: a true friend!  Add your own research to enhance your question.

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence as required by  the SWR tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Uplifting**. Here's what Google has as the definition:

> uplifting /ʌpˈlɪftɪŋ/
>
> morally or
>   spiritually elevating; inspiring happiness or hope.

That sounds about right, doesn't it?

Comment: No, you'd say that they're uplifting. As in, "Bob is so uplifting! He always makes me feel better."

Answer (score 0):

Angel would be a common term used for such a person.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/angel

Angel

5.

a.  A kind and lovable person.

b.  One who manifests goodness, purity, and selflessness.

Answer (score 0):

Affirming is also possible.

2. offer (someone) emotional support or encouragement.

It has the advantage that it can also be used unintuitively. There are people I like who I find affirming (intuitive use). There is one person I occasionally have to talk to who I cannot stand; however I usually feel better about myself after having done so - *I'm not that bad*!